# Import error and PythonPath

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to understand what the issue is:

I'm trying to import a module:

```
from main.models import Main
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Main)
```

However, when I attempt to hit the admin site, I get a django error page:

```
ImportError at /admin/
cannot import name Main

I noticed that it provides a dump of the **Python Path:**

Python Path:    ['/Users/brian/src/SampleApp/src/SampleApp', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode']
```

However, what I don't understand is where is this Python Path set?

doing an `export PYTHONPATH` returns nothing as it is not set in the environmental variables.

I need to import a module which is located in /Users/brian/src/SampleApp/src/SampleApp/main/models.py

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an `__init__.py` in `/Users/brian/src/SampleApp/src/SampleApp/main/`? This is required for the `main` directory to be considered for the search. An empty `__init__.py` will do.

You might also verify that `Main` is defined in there. Does a plain `import main.models` work?

Comment: Yes I have an empty __init__.py there... stupid me, Main is not there . that was it. Thanks.

Comment: any idea where the PYTHONPATH is set ?

Answer (score 4):

PYTHONPATH can be accessed via:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

A bit of debugging to try would be to use:

```
from main import models
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(models.Main)
```

and see if that gives you any more information.